# Signing message using web3 and using ethers gives different result. Why?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, keccak

I'm encoding a message using ethers' `solidityPackedKeccak256()`

```
const encodedMessage = ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(
            ["address", "uint256", "uint256"],
            [deployer.address, TOKEN_ID, NONCE],
        );
```

I'm signing this message using -

1. web3

   ```
    const { signature: signatureWeb3 } = web3.eth.accounts.sign(
                encodedMessage,
                HARDHAT_PRIVATE_KEY,
            );
   ```
2. ethers

   ```
    const signatureEthers = await deployer.signMessage(encodedMessage);
   ```

Their outputs are -

```
web3 =  0xc5b8d6ae2203e7f90257162289e552fac04b5708d4fe6b4360e86c2855db059314357f66bf89a2f72858980aa390607598defcb5382fea437ac4da3f725a9b231b
ethers =  0xaf7cb82eee6050746f299888ccc2a888d6801bff3701975ed5a73c73238b12a624fa575c9f8222ecaed25d2071c108477c84ac79572ceedf226f7a010f24511d1c
```

The message for both functions is same. So Why are both signatures different? How do I get the same result from ethers as web3's?

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different cryptography to sign the transactions on web3 and ethers.

Web3 `soliditySha3()` and for ethers `solidityPackedKeccak256()`

Instead you should implement `web3.utils.keccak256()` and `ethers.utils.keccak256()` to receive the same outputs signing ✍ the message.

Comment: Actually i used the same encoded message for both signature functions. So the message being passed as parameter is same for both accounts.sign() & sign(). Still both are giving different outputs.
I'll edit my question so it's more clear